# How to create a Makefile for a program which takes in command line argument

Tags: c, unix, makefile, terminal, cmd

I need to create a Makefile for a program which takes in a file as input via command line.

Here is what I mean:

A program has function main which looks like this:

```
int main(long argc, char **argv) //'argument command' and 'argument vector'respectively
{
  some code;
}
```

You compile this C language source code file

```
gcc main.c function1.c function2.c -o execute
```

Which creates an executable program called 'execute'. Then you pass in an argument into this program:

```
./execute filename
```

The makefile I've created has the contents:

```
all: xsd

xsd: main.o function1.o function2.o
    gcc -o xsd main. function1.o function2.o

main.o: main.c
    gcc -c -o main.o main.c

function1.o: function1.c
    gcc -c -o function1.c

function2.o: function2.c
    gcc -c -o function2.c

clean:
    rm -rf *o xsd
```

So how do I create a proper makefile which accomodates for the input file passed in via the command line? Perhaps something like this:

```
./{argv}
```

Anybody know how to do this?

Comment: Is your target `prog` or `xsd`? Or is your Makefile incomplete?

Comment: ... or `execute` or `executable`? Please edit your question so we don't have to speculate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just fix the type-o, and make all depend on xsd rather than prog...

```
all: xsd

xsd: main.o function1.o function2.o
    gcc -o xsd main.o function1.o function2.o

main.o: main.c
    gcc -c -o main.o main.c

function1.o: function1.c
    gcc -c -o function1.c

function2.o: function2.c
    gcc -c -o function2.c

clean:
    rm -rf *o xsd
```

Answer (score 1):

The make file doesn't run the program, it only compiles it, so it doesn't have to pass any parameters to it either.

Comment: But when I type make I get error, it prompts me for input files

Comment: Well, you could want to run it, too, but there is no straightforward way to use Make's arguments as an array to pass to a program. You might to something like `make T='foo bar baz' test` and have the `test` target run your program with `$T` as its command-line argument list.

Comment: Then the Makefile in your question is different from the one you are actually having a problem with.